# Почему может не доходить сообщение?

Tags: android, c#, сеть, xamarin, broadcast-receiver

Реализовал обмен broadcast сообщениями в winforms, все работает.
Перенес через xamarin на android и начались чудеса какие то...
Отправляю с телефона сообщение, клиент на компе(winforms) нормально принимает, а наоборот нет.
Почему-то теряется сообщение, есть какие-то мысли?

```
        public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
    private readonly UdpClient udp = new UdpClient(45000);
    public string mess= "";
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        StartListening();
        Button bt = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
        bt.Click += delegate { StartListening(); FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1).Text = mess; };
    }

    public void StartListening()
    {
        this.udp.BeginReceive(Receive, new object());
    }

    public void Receive(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 45000);
        byte[] bytes = udp.EndReceive(ar, ref ip);
        mess=Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
        StartListening();
    }
```

Comment: А через что android подключен к сети?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался, была блокировка wifi по умолчанию.